# Size of page table and number of entries

Tags: windows, 32-bit, virtual-memory, virtual-address-space

Suppose on 32 bit OS, we have 4 GB of available virtual address space. So, that means we need to map 2^32 = 4,294,967,296 addresses.

If you calculate the size to store all the 4,294,967,296 addresses in address space and if each is 4 bytes then it should take:

Size of memory for all addresses = 4,294,967,296 addresses x 4 bytes

**My question is:**

Does a single page table able to store that many addresses in their entries? If so, then why would the size of page table be only 4 MB as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23017707/187543)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual memory doesn't come in single bytes. A minimum unit of memory you can allocate, share, map, swap, lock etc. is a page of (usually) 4096 bytes.

The entire address space (4GB) is divided in 1Mi of such pages. That's why the entire table holds 1Mi of entries 4 bytes each, which is exactly 4 MB.